# What does the colon mean in this probabilty equation?

Tags: notation

$$
q\left(\mathbf{x}_{1: T} \mid \mathbf{x}_{0}\right)=\prod_{t=1}^{T} q\left(\mathbf{x}_{t} \mid \mathbf{x}_{t-1}\right)
$$

What dose the $\mathbf{x}_{1: T}$ mean?
This is from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1noQ2d4-nzSh3Yp3-mOOYN8YGJoSa4pmz/view page 17.

Comment: It denotes the range of x... From $X_1$ to $X_T$

Comment: Thx for such an immediate reply. So the $T$ can be replaced with a value in the range from 1 to $T$?

Comment: No.  $x_{1:T}$ represents the sequence of images $x_1, \cdots, x_T$.  It's a *path* through image space.  The right-hand side tells you that your process is independent at each step (to get to $x_1$, you only use information from $x_0$ is "$q(x_1 \mid x_0)$" and so on.  So this is basically a statement that the process under discussion only uses the previous image to get the next one -- that is, the increments are independent.

Comment: Thx guys, really needed it.